# Any way, hook to add content right before the "read more" link?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks

I'm trying to add the 'Hello world' from this code:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
  return $content . ' <br /> Hello World ';
}, 0);
```

Before the "read more" link that that sends to single page.
As you can see this code ads the hello word after the "read more", and I would like it just before, but after the rest of the content.

Is there a hook for this?
If possible I prefer to keep this in functions.php rather than in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use the filter `the_content_more_link`.

Here is the example

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'q363666_tweak_more_link', 10, 2 );
function q363666_tweak_more_link( $more_link, $more_link_text ) {
  // WordPress prepared the $more_link
  // you can intercept here and return whatever you need
  return 'Hello World ' . $more_link;
}
```